# jquery/ajax not working in ie9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have coded an environment for ie8 (internal, corporate).

Recently, we started ie9 deployment testing (i know, its so far behind....)

The app I work on does not work.

I changed the xua ie=edge to ie=8 and ie9 works, but for obvious reasons i don't want to limit ie 9 to ie8s rendering engine.

The areas that don't work are ajax population calls on a menu.   ie, it prints

```
 <ul id = "ul_a1">   <li>loading...</li>  </ul>
```

from source, and 
then

```
var request = $.ajax({  
    url: "xxurlxxx"
    ,  type: "GET"              
    ,  cache: false
    ,  dataType: "html"
});
request.done(function(msg) {
    $("#ul_a1").html(msg);  
});
```

fills it in (this call returns a bunch of li's) with the option list.

the area stays on 'loading...' and the request.fail never fires either.

What about this method does ie9 not like?
URL is local, not xdomain.

Comment: What's the error it gives?

Comment: Does any error appear in the Developer Tools? (Press F12 on your page)

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console window?

Comment: I did notice that you have a <ul> with id=a1, but you use #ul_a1 as a selector. This is incorrect... You should use ul#a1

Comment: @MrP I agree but then that wouldn't work in IE8 either.

Comment: try use `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log('ERROR: ' + textStatus + ' -- ' + errorThrown, jqXHR);}` inside `$.ajax` instead of `.done` and `.fail``. It might give you a better view of what error is.

Comment: The Id was simply a typo here, shortened for example purposes.  the id's do match in the app.  sorry.

Comment: To calify, there is NO error.  it simply doesn't seem to actually trigger/function/do the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is looking to be not the issue at all.  Rather, a prior loaded html5 canvas element is throwing a dom exception error which is causing everthing after it to break.

ie8 doesn't use canvas, it uses divs.   ie9 must be trying to render it (i'm using an excanvas include with flot graphing lib).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "xxurlxxx",
    type: "GET",          
    cache: false,
    data: {
       someparam: "somevalue"
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        // do something with data
    }
});
```

If you're just adding some html generated serverside then you can try:

```
$('#element').load(url);
```

If this doesn't help then probably you need to encode your url.

Comment: The url is simple (1 int param) page?do=actionID so i do not beleive it to be an encoding issue.   I used load in the past, and it didn't seem to work as i expected it to.   Additionally, my post requests are also failing in some places, so the load won't work for that.

Comment: @briansol then you must put `url:"page",data:{'do':actionID}`

Comment: it's a get, not a post.